# Magallanes deploy unable to connect via ssh key

Tags: php, symfony, ssh

I am trying to deploy a Symfony2 PHP project on Ubuntu 15.10 with [MagePHP](http://magephp.com/), but it always asks me for the SSH users password when executing:

```
sudo php vendor/andres-montanez/magallanes/bin/mage deploy to:staging
```

When checking the log I can see it stops at this command:

```
ssh  -p 22 -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ssh-user@my-domain.com "sh -c \"mkdir -p /customers/489176_10999/websites/my_company/symfony/staging/releases/20160902094526\""
```

Executing this command by itself works fine (so the server accepts the ssh key), but from within the context of the deployment script it doesn't.

I am quite puzzled by this, since both commands are run from the same directory. Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file has been located under `/var/www` the `ssh-agent` had no access to the key files, since they were stored under the user directory. Moving the entire project inside the user directory fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try running the deploy with sudo.
Regards!

Comment: If you look at the first command mentioned in the description you can see that I already run with `sudo`.